# Laravel How to pass variable from select box to url?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, routes

What I am trying to do is basicly passing selected item's slug from a select box to route

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'list/{category->slug(here)}' ]) }}
<select name="" id="" class="form-control">
    @foreach($categories $category)
        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
{{ Form::submit('Send') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You will need javascript to do this. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some javascript (jQuery) to do this

```
$("#select").change(function() {
  var option = $(this).val();
  $("#form-id").attr("action", "list/" + option);
});
```

Comment: You should mention that your answer uses jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the onchange. Like here:

```
<select onchange="document.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option value="{{ route('route_name') }}">caption</option>
```